# Standard way of getting a non-specialized std::vector<bool> container

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

Is there a standard way (or at least semi-standard, implemented in all popular compilers) to get a non-specialized, non-optimized, contiguous `std::vector<bool>` container?

I have some generic code dealing with `std::vector`s which assumes they are all such standard, contiguous containers. My current workaround is to use a `std::vector<int>` which just stores 0's and 1's, which is what I want content-wise, but it would be nicer to have the correct vector type.

Comment: At least, you can save some space by using a `std::vector<char>`, as char has the same size as bool...

Comment: Is it an option to change the generic code to use the vector's index operator or (possibly even better) iterators?

Comment: @Aconcagua - There is no guarantee `bool` is the size of a `char`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Not according to the standard, but I've never seen anything else in the past 15 years... Could we accept it as *de facto* standard?

Comment: @Aconcagua - No we can't. And as a matter of fact, on systems where accessing individual bytes is costly, it actually makes sense to have `bool` be the native word size.

Comment: @StoryTeller But at least it would definitely not waste space since char is the smallest possible type.

Comment: @VTT - Not arguing with that.

Comment: If you want to make an assumption like that bool and char are the same size, just static_assert it and move on.   It won't ever actually byte you, and you can feel good about your code.

Comment: @Aconcagua Unfortunately not in my specific case. Some of my classes use `std::vector`s as their storage and others use other containers. Each such class must provide the same interface of read-access to its storage via a pointer to memory which is impossible with the specialized `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: @Danra - Is it likely `std::vector<bool>` will ever actually used with your code base? It's considered so much of a design mistake people are usually advised to avoid it.

Comment: @Danra But you *are* aware that most other containers don't even provide contiguous memory (std::deque, std::list, ...)? If they do, they possibly don't use it in a contiguous way (std::unordered_set, ...)???

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes. I am using it myself. (or, I would have, if it had the standard semantics. Since it doesn't, using the less-type-correct workaround)

Comment: @Aconcagua The other containers involved (non-STL ones) do provide contiguous memory.

Comment: Ever thought of there might be a good reason for that all STL algorithms operate on iterators? You would gain much flexibility if you changed the common interface to provide such iterators and then use them in your generic code (consider reusability of code). Problems with `std::vector<bool>` covered for free then...

Comment: @Aconcagua I am aware of iterators and their advantages. I believe further discussing my specific case, and whether I even *need* a non-specialized `std::vector<bool>` would be beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @Danra I did not intend to discuss neither advantages nor necessities, but instead to inspire to think about a redesign of the generic code as *solution* to your problem. I am pretty aware that this requires quite a lot of work, and it is up to you to decide if it is worth the effort... (A variant with possibly less effort could be providing index operators to the custom containers and base the generic code on these.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167628/discussion-between-danra-and-aconcagua).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As workaround you might use other type, `char` comes in mind.
Else you can write a wrapper around `bool`, something like:

```
struct my_bool
{
    operator bool() const { return b; }
    operator bool&() { return b; }

    bool b;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, use of `std::vector<bool>` specialization is not consider a good practice, with exceptions of-course. Mainly, because its interface is different with that of the primary `std::vector<T>` and this causes a lot of confusion.

This irregularity, is mentioned in several publications that are loose in the web. A recent one and IMHO a good read is written by Howard Hinnant namely [On `vector<bool>`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html).

In fact sometime ago there was a proposal to remove it from from the standard [N1185](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/N1185.pdf), but it was rejected for backward compatibility issues.

Most proposed semi-standard alternative is the use of `std::vector<unsigned char>` or `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Not really, at least not significant. My guess is that 0 converts to `false` while any number != 0 to `true` so for some peculiar reason you would want to rule out the negative numbers.